# Simple product image in search results

Tags: magento-1.9, product, search

I'm currently in the process of setting up a Magento store-front (v1.9). Our products are set up as configurable products. We have an image for the configurable products and an image for each simple product within it. On the category index page there is a filter option so people can filter our products by color. The problem is, in the filtered results they are shown the configurable product image rather than that simple product image.

For example, all our configurable product images are set to the brown version of our product. If a user searches by "green" to see all our green products, they are shown all the results of products available in green, but the images are still brown. Is it possible to set up Magento so it shows the green images of those products instead?